# Affine cipher decryption, output differs for upper case and lower case

Tags: c++, encryption, ascii

I have the problem when decrypting a plaintext using Affine cipher.
Encryption works fine, but applying the same logic for decryption of lower case/upper case characters returns different output.

Here is the output:

Encrypted Message is : ulctkbsjarizqhypgxofwnevmd ULCTKBSJARIZQHYPGXOFWNEVMD
Decrypted Message is: opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

I suspect it has something to do with retrieving of ASCII values, can someone correct me?

Here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

//Key values of a and b 
const int a = 17; 
const int b = 20; 

string encryptMessage(string plainText) 
{ 
    string cipher = ""; 

    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) 
    { 
        if(plainText[i]!=' ') 
        {
            if ((plainText[i] >= 'a' && plainText[i] <= 'z') || (plainText[i] >= 'A' && plainText[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
                if (plainText[i] >= 'a' && plainText[i] <= 'z')
                {
                    cipher = cipher + (char) ((((a * (plainText[i]-'a') ) + b) % 26) + 'a'); 
                }

                else if (plainText[i] >= 'A' && plainText[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                    cipher = cipher + (char) ((((a * (plainText[i]-'A') ) + b) % 26) + 'A');
                }

            }
            else
            {
                cipher += plainText[i]; 
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cipher += plainText[i]; 
        }

    } 
    return cipher; 
} 

string decryptCipher(string cipher) 
{ 
    string plainText = ""; 
    int aInverse = 0; 
    int flag = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    { 
        flag = (a * i) % 26; 

        if (flag == 1) 
        { 
            aInverse = i; 
        } 
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < cipher.length(); i++) 
    { 
        if(cipher[i] != ' ') 
        {
            if ((cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z') || (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
                if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
                {
                    plainText = plainText + (char) ((((aInverse * (cipher[i]+ 'a') ) - b) % 26) + 'a'); 

                }

                else if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                    plainText = plainText + (char) (((aInverse * ((cipher[i]+'A' - b)) % 26)) + 'A'); 

                }

            }
            else
            {
                plainText += cipher[i]; 
            }           
        }
        else

            plainText += cipher[i]; 
    } 

    return plainText; 

} 

//Driver Program 
int main(void) 
{ 
    string msg = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 

    //Calling encryption function 
    string cipherText = encryptMessage(msg); 
    cout << "Encrypted Message is : " << cipherText<<endl; 

    //Calling Decryption function 
    cout << "Decrypted Message is: " << decryptCipher(cipherText); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: change `((((a * (plainText[i]-'a') ) + b) % 26) + 'a')` to `(((((a * (plainText[i]-'a') ) + b) % 26) + 'a') % 26)`

Comment: Every occurrence of your `a` and `b` variables is a compiler error. Did you mean `'a'` and `'b'`?

Comment: ... For example, in this line: `cipher = cipher + (char) ((((a * (plainText[i]-'A') ) + b) % 26) + 'A');` you use `a` and `b` - but where are these declared and/or defined?

Comment: @AdrianMole a and b are the keys for affine cipher. following formula of E ( x ) = ( a x + b ) mod m and D ( x ) = a^-1 ( x - b ) mod m

Comment: Then ***please*** include those definitions in your posted code! (I tried to compile your code to see where the problem was, and couldn't because of the errors - which is why we ask for a minimal *reproducible* example!!)

Comment: @kelalaka Could you explain why changing that matters? As mentioned encryption works (the code you suggested to change), only decryption does not work for lower case.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have edited the code such that it can be executed. Would appreciate your input now!

Comment: If I were you, I would check the range of the ciphertext characters after encryption....

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this for some time and, although I can't provide a *complete* explanation, I have a couple of 'observations' that may be useful, plus a 'cheat' workaround.

First, although you say you use *"the same logic for decryption of lower case/upper case,"* a character-wise alignment of the code from each of your decryption blocks shows that this isn't *quite* true:

```cpp
plainText = plainText + (char) ((((aInverse * (cipher[i]+ 'a') ) - b) % 26) + 'a'); // Lower case
plainText = plainText + (char) (((aInverse * ((cipher[i]+'A' - b)) % 26)) + 'A');   // Upper case
```

So, 'fixing' the lower case code to be *exactly analogous* to the (working) code for upper case (and removing redundant parentheses) gives this:

```cpp
if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
{
    plainText = plainText + (char)( ( (aInverse * (cipher[i] + 'a' - b) ) % 26 ) + 'a' );
}
else if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
{
    plainText = plainText + (char)( ( (aInverse * (cipher[i] + 'A' - b) ) % 26 ) + 'A' );
}
```

However, this doesn't actually resolve the issue (it just changes it slightly), as the output then is as follows:

```
Encrypted Message is : ulctkbsjarizqhypgxofwnevmd ULCTKBSJARIZQHYPGXOFWNEVMD
Decrypted Message is : qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnop ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

The problem here is that the lowercase values are all 'rotated' by the value `16` - which looks suspiciously close to the value for `a`. Also, note that, although `a` is used in the encryption formula, it is *not* used in your decryption.

So, I have come up with the following workaround, assuming that (for reasons yet to be deduced) when decoding upper case values, this `16` is somehow lost in the bit-representation of the ASCII values:

```cpp
if ((cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z') || (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z'))
{
    int offset = ((cipher[i] - 'A') / 26) ? a - 1 : 0;
    if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z') {
        plainText = plainText + (char)( ( (aInverse * (cipher[i] + 'a' - b) - offset ) % 26 ) + 'a' );
    }
    else if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z') {
        plainText = plainText + (char)( ( (aInverse * (cipher[i] + 'A' - b) - offset ) % 26 ) + 'A' );
    }
}
```

Note that your code can be further simplified/clarified using functions provided by the standard library and removing some 'redundant' checks:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < cipher.length(); i++) {
    if (isalpha(cipher[i])) {
        int offset = islower(cipher[i]) ? a - 1 : 0;
        int letter = islower(cipher[i]) ? 'a' : 'A';
        plainText = plainText + (char)(((aInverse * (cipher[i] + letter - b) - offset) % 26) + letter);
    }
    else {
        plainText += cipher[i];
    }
}
```